# How to render the same 404 page for all unknown requests, including images, in Rails 3.2 without specifying each file format individually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, actionview

We use the following catch-all route in routes.rb for 404s:

```
# Catches all 404 errors and redirects
match '*url' => 'default#error_404'
```

But this generates a 500 internal server error below because we don't specifically catch PNG formats in **error_404**.

```
Started GET "/images/doesnotexistyo.png" for 71.198.44.101 at 2013-03-08 07:59:24 +0300
Processing by DefaultController#error_404 as PNG
  Parameters: {"url"=>"images/doesnotexistyo"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template default/error_404, application/error_404 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:png], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/prod/Prod/app/views"
```

Ideally, all unknown requests would render the **default#error_404 HTML** action. We can't figure out how to get **format.any** to render the 404 HTML action. How can all unknown requests get rendered with the error 404 HTML response?

Answer (score 4):

**in Application Controller:** [Use rescue_from](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from)

```
rescue_from "ActionController::UnknownAction", :with => :render_404
rescue_from "ActionController::RoutingError",  :with => :render_404

def render_404
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :template => "<PATH_OF_404_ERROR_TEMPLATE>", :status => 404 }       
    format.xml { head 404 }
    format.js { head 404 }
    format.json { head 404 }
  end
  return false
end
```

Comment: what does return false do?

Comment: I don't see any reason for return false either.